# Where should I store a small amount of data for my application?

Tags: storage

I am going to make a program for learning languages and I want to add words to the dictionary so I can check them whenever I want to. I am going to store the word, its translation, definition and example(s) of use.

I can use databases but I am afraid it is too much because once i finish this little project I want to convert it to .exe file (I am using python) and send it to my friends and I don't want them to download SQL DBMS.

I have seen some ideas like - store it in .csv or .xml or even .txt files but I am not sure if it's the best option.

Comment: You can use `sqlite` which is packaged with Python, so you *could* use a database, but you can use whatever you want, just a simple text file, maybe csv, which you parse yourself, or serialize it with JSON or pickle.

Comment: Maybe take a look at the often overlooked [`shelve`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/shelve.html#module-shelve) module. It offers a persistent dictionary with a dict-like interface.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the most appropriate way of storing a dictionary is by using a .json file. IIRC the python package `json` makes importing and exporting easier.

Comment: I think he meant dictionary in the Webster's sense, not the Python sense.

Comment: Even so the data listed would fit perfectly in a JSON file, and can be accessed using Python directories.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SQLite as database.
It does not require to install a DBMS and once you create the .exe all the modules from python to use it are included